# Any existing solutions for dynamic forms in Django?

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, forms

I'm looking for existing solutions for building dynamic forms with Django. What I want to get is a form that looks just like a table, but when any of its cells are clicked, textbox is dynamically displayed instead of the text and then user can edit the value.

I know that's quite an abstract description but I'd really appreciate everything related: if that library/framework will reload absolutely all table to switch it from completely read-only to completely editable, that's also fine.

I'm implementing a proof of concept web application, so I'd like to avoid spending time for implementing it from scratch.

The description is unclear, I believe. Here it is:

1. There's a list of users for instance. Just a simple table. Administrator clicks one of these users and profile is displayed:

   > Login: jsmith
   >
   > Real Name: John Smith
   >
   > Group: Users
2. Then administrator double-clicks "John Smith" and text box is loaded instead of text:

   > Login: jsmith
   >
   > Real Name: [ John Smith ]
   >
   > Group: Users
   >
   > [Save] [Cancel]
3. Administrator can now modify jsmith's real name. If Save is clicked, data is sent to server. If Cancel is clicked, data is reverted and profile is as on p.1

**Update: what I want is what we have here on stackoverflow.com - write a comment (not answer) and post it. Then you can edit it without reloading the page. That's what I've been talking about before. So, I need something of that kind but extendable and Django-injectable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is a Javascript Data Grid widget. The Ext JS toolkit has a nice example, something like this:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/grid/cell-editing.html

Now note this has nothing to do with Django, these things can be deployed by any web server or application server.

Of course implementing this on a Django server just means making sure your server is serving the Javascript, and that you've written any Ajax calls correctly. But thats the next step.

Comment: Well, the idea is, I'm looking for solution that makes it possible to absolutely get rid of working with JS. I'd like to just create the form the trivial Django way, bind it to model, etc. I can spend like 16 hours and implement it, but I just don't want messing with it.

Comment: Please, review the question - I've added some clarifications. And also, don't edit tags please.

Comment: When you say 'table' I think 'grid', which is what TABLE tags are for. That's partly what sent me up the wrong track. Much clearer now. Also, tags are editable so we can edit them :)

Comment: Pardon my English, I'm not a native speaker, so I have some problems using apt words ;) So, since we're clear with it, any other ideas?

Comment: This won't be possible without JavaScript. I haven't seen a django-app that provides this solution either. Essentially you'll need to use a library like Spacedman suggests and handle the various callbacks in your own JS code and django views.

Comment: If anyone gets this working, can you please post a snippet somewhere? I will do the same, however, my js/ajax skills are minimal... we'll see...

Answer (score 2):

I found [InplaceEditForm](http://tracpub.yaco.es/djangoapps/wiki/InplaceEditForm) which is easy to install from the svn (link at bottom of page) and it's really straight forward to setup. It's not as nice as the JS kit mentioned by spacedman, but it works easily. Note that you have to be logged in with edit permissions to be able to use it (that took me a while to figure out). So just log into your admin then go back to your test page.

It would be fine for editing a couple fields here and there, but I'm looking for spreadsheet like editing (like spacedman's link) so I will probably keep searching

Comment: Already moved to GWT, since Django appeared to be too low-level solution for this kind of tasks. But thanks ;-)

Comment: guess it depends on the scope of the site. seems like it jsut takes a lot of js/jquery/ajax/whatever knowledge to implement something like this. not many exisiting packages and/or guides on how to easily implement it in django for the asynchonous novice. might have to check out gwt for fun.

Comment: Absolutely agree here. This CAN be implemented from scratch using Django and JavaScript, but it requires time. GWT allows just to never think about it